# Why are there multiple answers to the MLE of the binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood

I have been trying to figure out the MLE of the binomial distribution but online, several different sources have different answers.

For example, source 1 (http://cnx.org/content/m13500/latest/) gives:

[image]

Now source 2 (http://wolfweb.unr.edu/~zal/STAT653_Fall12/HW2_sol.pdf) yields:

[image]
[image]

Why is it that one answer gives just $\frac{k}{n}$ while the other yields the sum of x's over n? Thanks!

Comment: Because $X_i$ (and $x_i$ with it) was *defined differently*. Think about the two definitions of $X$ carefully, and then you should be able to tell me what "$m$" would be for the first one (not by guessing from the estimator, but directly from what $x_i$ *is*). It might help to look back through those sources at the (probably immediately adjacent) prior material.

Comment: I believe that in the first example, we are trying to find the probability of having k successes in n trials? In other words, X is just defined as the probability it took a 0 or 1?

In the second, are we having m DIFFERENT experiments, each with n trials? In other words, the way to connect the first and the second is to let m=1? Thanks!

Comment: $X_i$ isn't a probability. $X_i$ is a random variable that can (in the first case) be 0 or 1, and $x_i$ is the observed value (a 0 or a 1). But yes, as you say, the first one corresponds to m=1.